# Add a Row After 6 Records Automatically

Tags: php, html

Here Is The Code

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9 column">
        <div class="services-listing">
        <?php  if(!empty($data)):
            foreach ($data as $rows ) : ?>
          <div class="service">
            <div class="service-img"><span><img src="dashboard/uploads/<?php echo $rows['img'];?>" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="service-detail"> 
              <h3><a href="#" title=""><?php echo $rows['name'];?></a></h3>

            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Service -->
          <?php endforeach; else : echo "No Record Found Against This Services"; endif;?>
        </div>
        <!-- Service Listing --> 
      </div>
```

i want to start design from `<div class="row">` not from `<div class="service">` now it repeating this div i want new `<div class="row">` genrated after every 6 records

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9 column">
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: where do you want to put that new div row? Bellow existing div row?

Comment: i want to start design from <div class="row"> not from <div class="service"> now it repeating this div i want new <div class="row"> genrated after every 6 records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking for something like this, let me know if it works for you

```
<?php
$start = 6;
$end = 1;

if(!empty($data)){

    foreach ($data as $rows ) {

        if ($start % 6 == 0) { ?>

        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9 column">

        <?php } ?>

                <div class="services-listing">

                    <div class="service">
                        <div class="service-img"><span><img src="dashboard/uploads/<?php echo $rows['img'];?>" alt="" /></div>
                        <div class="service-detail">
                            <h3><a href="#" title=""><?php echo $rows['name'];?></a></h3>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Service -->

                </div>

        <?php if ($end % 6 == 0) { ?>

        </div>
        </div>

        <?php } $start++; $end++;

    }
}
else{ echo "No Record Found Against This Services"; }
```

?>

Comment: If my answer was helpful to resolve your question then please up-vote and accept. ;)

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap div row with `foreach` first and then:

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>    
<?php  if(!empty($data)):
                    foreach ($data as $rows ) : ?>
<?php $i++; ?>
        <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-9 column">
                <div class="services-listing">

                  <div class="service">
                    <div class="service-img"><span><img src="dashboard/uploads/<?php echo $rows['img'];?>" alt="" /></div>
                    <div class="service-detail"> 
                      <h3><a href="#" title=""><?php echo $rows['name'];?></a></h3>

                    </div>
                   <!-- Service -->
                  </div>
                <!-- Service Listing -->
                </div>
              <!-- col-md-9 column -->
              </div>
           <!-- Row --> 
          </div>
    <?php if($i%6==0):?>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-9 column">
              </div>
          </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; else : echo "No Record Found Against This Services"; endif;?>
```

just please re-check all divs structure to be sure whether all of them are closed